# Не будет ли на ГИА считаться за тавтологию повторение слова "история" (с другим падежом)?

Tags: предлоги, синонимы, тавтология, анализ-текста

> Донецкий художественный музей — один из крупных музеев Донбасса. В
>   1939 году основан как Музей изобразительного искусства. Его история
>   насчитывает в своей коллекции более пятнадцати тысяч произведений
>   живописи, графики, скульптуры. Посещая это место, я погружаюсь в
>   историю древних скифов, изучаю первые древние поселения кочующих
>   племён, но больше всего мне нравится описание шахтёрского быта,
>   тяжёлые и неугомонные будни обычного шахтёра.

1. В правилах к ГИА нет слова "тавтология", но написано:

   > следить, чтобы основные тематические слова не повторялись, заменять
   >   повторы синонимами.

Но в данном случае трудно подобрать синоним. И разве это "основное тематическое слово"?

2. Можно ли заменить первое предложение на

> Донецкий художественный музей — один из самых крупных в Донбассе.

"В/на Донбассе" как-то некрасиво звучит. Могут ли на экзамене за такое балл снизить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Повторение слова "*история*" не тянет на [**тавтологию**](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)), которая представляет собой **необоснованное повторение** одних и тех же (или однокоренных) или близких по смыслу слов («спросить вопрос»). В представленном тексте слово повторяется в разных предложениях и не очень режет слух, хотя, безусловно, заметно. Скорее, это можно отнести к стилистической погрешности.

Но дело даже не в этом. Сочетание "***история*** насчитывает **в своей коллекции**" некорректно. Выход, на мой взгляд, простой — нужно написать: ***Его коллекция насчитывает...*** И нет никакого повтора.

2. Заменить "один из крупных" на "один из **самых** крупных" можно. Вероятно, Донецкий музей и является самым крупным в Донбассе, но другие музеи теоретически могут с ним конкурировать по "крупности" чего-то другого (площади, количества залов, филиалов, редких экспонатов и др.). Одно из значений слова "крупный" — значительный, а таких музеев может быть много.

В Национальном корпусе русского языка [именно такое сочетание](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) встречается 79 раз, например:

*Отряд Попаснянского района, **один из самых крупных** в области* <...> [А. А. Фадеев. Молодая гвардия]

*Сегодня Северо-Запад, конечно, **один из самых крупных** транзитных транспортных узлов* <...> [Марина Скляренко. Премия «Эксперт года» — шаг в большую экспертную политику]

Из Википедии: *Миссисипи имеет **один из самых больших** бассейнов в мире.*

3. За ***на Донбассе*** оценку снизить могут. Такое сочетание часто можно услышать (и этому есть своё объяснение). Я родом из Кемерова (Кузбасс) и никогда ни от кого не слышал ***на Кузбассе***.

[**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5):

> Всё очень просто: *Донбасс* – сокращение от *Донецкий угольный бассейн*. По-русски говорят *в бассейне*, не *на бассейне*. Поэтому *в Донбассе*.

А вообще, чтобы избежать и этой неловкости, используйте беспредложный вариант.

P. S. Благодаря комментарию автора вопроса заметил, что в предложении  "*Донецкий художественный музей — один из самых крупных в Донбассе*" не только добавлено слово "*самый*" и предлог "*в*" (на чём я и сконцентрировался в своем ответе), но и отсутствует слово "*музей*" из изначального текста. Повтор этого слова, так же как и история с "*историей*", звучит неблагозвучно :) и может вызвать вопросы, тем более что "*Музей*" присутствует и во втором предложении. Поэтому беспредложный вариант отпадает.

Comment: бесприставочный вариант опять-таки не сильно приятен. У нас учительница советует нам использовать одинаковые слова лишь через 1 предложения. В её теории фраза "Донецкий художественный музей - один из крупных музеев Донбасса" - тоже тавтология, но мб меня будет проверять не такой как она. Хотя на Донбассе и не такое бывает)

Comment: @askobar  Безприставочный - Вы имеете в виду безпредложный? Почему не приятен? Тогда пишите _в  Донбассе_ и не ошибётесь. Согласен, что повторение _музей_  и _музеев_  не очень звучит. Пишите так: Донецкий музей - один из самых крупных в Донбассе. Да, если не повторять _музеи_ то без предлога никак.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: И вам за вопрос!  Приятно иметь дело с благодарными участниками!

Comment: Хочу оправдаться за приставку "без" в предыдущем комментарии. На протяжении двух лет редактирую книги, автор которых категорически не принимает приставку "бес", следует дореволюционным правилам. Видимо, это уже въелось в мое подсознание :)